# Python function for searching Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a simple method to search a `pandas` dataframe column for a list of keywords; however, I'd like to create a function to pass a word (or words) through so I don't need to continuously update my search list.

My current method:

```
keywords = ['keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3', 'keyword4']
searched_keywords = '|'.join(keywords)
df= df[df['text'].str.contains(searched_keywords, na=False)]
print(df)
```

What I'd like to accomplish:

```
def search(keyword):
    search = '|'.join(keyword)
    searched = df[df['text'].str.contains(search, na=False)]
    return searched
```

I would then call `search(keyword)` and update the dataframe with the columns containing the search terms. I'm running into an issue though where the dataframe is being returned without the keywords. Where am I going wrong?

**Data (example search term 'pokemon'):**

```
index text
1,Pokemon crashed in me ðŸ˜¤
2,Who knew that that baggage claim would be more hypnotic than Pokemon Go.  Nadi /MSOmSnHPNs
3,Get a SecretDoubleDown with every Pokemonster found today.
4,Anyone out there with a Fitbit add me and let's get competitive. This Pokemon Go stuff is goodâ€¦ /iw194ni6kH
5,What happens when the PokemonGo craze is over. Will they all just be left to roam the streets like the homeless?
6,Gotta Catch Em All! pokemongo pokemon ratata oddish pidgey eeve rhihorn doduo magmarâ€¦ /6KCbkcKIBo
7,I found ãƒ”ã‚¸ãƒ§ãƒ³ in McDonald's pokemongo pokemon game play game ã¯ã¾ã£ã¦ã„ã‚‹ getã ãœ macdonalds getâ€¦ /DWD4Bh3RI9
8,Had a stand off against this Koffing in town today. Don't worry I caught it ðŸ‘  PokemonGOâ€¦ /IPaT7bEDeI
9,Mencari Pokemon with the genkss ðŸ¤˜ðŸ»ðŸ‘»ðŸ‘½ðŸ˜… (at The Square) [pic] â€” /tWLtjRhIP9
10,Waikato uni pokemon go fever pokemongo waikatouniversity â€¦ /UomascadDf
11,Where pokemon go has taken me ðŸ˜‚  Hamilton Gardens /fHmAd8kFrQ
12,Caught myself a Pidgeot! ðŸ¥ pokemongo newzealand  Hamilton Gardens /av4LfD3eEt
13,My prized possession ðŸ˜ pokemongo jigglypuff walkingisgoodformeâ€¦ /XJ1KGgVglK
14,Hahaha thetruth truth pokemongo pokemon niantic smartphone android iphone gameâ€¦ /PjNOYdJy5L
15,On an adventure for Pokemon â€¢  Garden Place /4m9TviEq31
16,pokemonðŸ˜‚hamiltonchartwellstarbuckspokemonpokemonballstrawberryvanilla goodãƒã‚±ãƒ¢ãƒ³ â€¦ /vnWbbrsBsY
17,When ur boss and team member are walking around catching Pokemon at work lol Hahahaha pokemongoâ€¦ /Qr6Q4Je6Bq
18,Ran out of balls so had to use tubes but this one got away   pokemongo pokemonâ€¦ /OjUGUDbZib
19,Our first Pokemon in the house! Amber was so excited she pounced on it! PokemonGo  The Dansion /w8sWppGMk6
20,Pokemon hunting solo! ( Howick Beach in Howick
21,Gorgeous day for a walk. wellingtonnz nature catchingpokemon  Tihati Bay
22,Lures are ON at The Flying Moa PokÄ“ Stop pokemongo theflyingmoa flyingmoa pokemongoaucklandâ€¦ /FVWaI3b0u6
23,While waiting for a pokemon to appear we saw this real life "thing" as Chris called it.â€¦ /WPXUmxvVS8
24,Pokemon go is a danger to my health. It's real blood.this is a real injury. dontpokemonanddriveâ€¦ /dFXecLSElG
25,If I was to catch how many people are playing Pokemon Go
26,is still get hair done
27,i had no class todai why did i wait 630 to start do everyth
28,passei o dia com o meu amor comemo demai <3 @guugaraujo
29,4 hari ngga ada kepsek rasanya nyaman bgt kerjaan juga lebih teratur tp skalinya doi masuk administrasi kacau balau lg yanasib
30,never a dull moment with emma <3 twitter/MLEFFin_awesome/status/431584519951749120/photo/1
31,good morn
32,that Oikos commerci with @johnstamos @bobsaget and @davecoulier is better than my whole life #takesmeback #youcankissmeanytimejohn
33,rememb when we would go to club zoo :D
34,@itscourtney_365 thei call
35,when you see your hometown in your english book twitter/norastanky/status/431584528302223360/photo/1
36,i'm at longhorn steakhouse brandon fl 4sq/1bzZsrp
37,@tonichopchop moron drive me nut
38,my god sister got drink
39,andrÃ© vc e o vitor estÃ£o de parabÃ©n pela dupla melhor do que a do Pliny_the_Elder @esp_interativo #onordestemerece #esporteinterativo
40,:yes: California_Pizza_Kitchen instagram/p/kGDyoYm7lM/
41,@jjoshjjosh @piersmorgan bewar josh you miss a comma befor the word know in your Twitter he'll have you for that #grammar
42,morn
43,thi be that tbt 8) twitter/pinoy_boiiiii/status/431584549273751553/photo/1
44,im here twitter/aaaaatkh/status/431584549290516482/photo/1
45,@_shortyyy_ hahaha i bet that great :D
46,twitter/Mahfuz_Eugene/status/431584553501589504/photo/1
47,ã¡ã‚‡ã£ã¨ã¾ã£ã¦ :no: é…åˆ»ã‹ã‚‚ã‹ã‚‚ã‹ã‚‚ç¬‘
48,sorri yeee ga ada kta galau d kamu ku :P @rita_agustinaa emangnya kamu @arinisukawati statusnya galau :P @rita_agustinaa oiya
49,me estoi quedando fritiiita
```

Comment: What keywords are you using? Do you have a sample of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your function and it works. The problem may be the `keyword` values that you pass.

I have made a small change to your function in order to make it a little more useful:

```
def search(keyword, df):
    search = '|'.join(keyword)
    searched = df[df['text'].str.contains(search, na=False)]
    return searched
```

Example:

```
df2 = search(["Pokemon"], df)

df2.head()
    index   text
0   1   Pokemon crashed in me ðŸ˜¤
1   2   Who knew that that baggage claim would be more...
2   3   Get a SecretDoubleDown with every Pokemonster ...
3   4   Anyone out there with a Fitbit add me and let'...
4   5   What happens when the PokemonGo craze is over....
```

and then you could keep searching the new `df2`

```
df3 = search(["craze","crash"], df2)

df3.head()
    index   text
0   1   Pokemon crashed in me ðŸ˜¤
4   5   What happens when the PokemonGo craze is over....
```

**Possible Problems**

If you pass a string

```
search("Pokemon", df)
```

you'll be searching for `'P|o|k|e|m|o|n'`

The dataframe `df` must have a column named 'text' or you'll get an error.

If you keep doing `df = search(['search text 1'], df)` (or `df = search(['search text 1'])` with your original function) over and over with different terms you may end up with an empty dataframe. If you reassign the search result to `df` you will be effectively doing an `and` between the different keywords.